# Refresh function does not work as expected Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

So, I have this app which loads rss feeds and I have implemented refresh function. Upload refreshing, it does reloads and adds the new post if it's posted but the previous data stays there and gets added on to the stack. Check the code and images. I am attaching below.

```
//
//  TableViewController.swift
//  WebView
//

import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController,XMLParserDelegate{

    var currentElement:String = ""
    var postTitle:String = ""
    var webLink:String = ""
    var feeds:[Model] = []
    var reload: UIRefreshControl! = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://sensodyneforsensitiveteeth.wordpress.com/feed")!
        let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://froshgeek.com/feed")!
        let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: urlToSend as URL)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        //reload
        reload!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to reload the page")
        reload!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.reloadFunc), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(reload)
        reload.endRefreshing()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        currentElement=elementName;
        if(elementName=="item")
        {
            postTitle = String()
            webLink = String()
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if(elementName=="item"){
            let feed: Model = Model()
            feed.postTitle = postTitle
            feed.webLink = webLink
            feeds.append(feed)

        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\\s*", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        if (!data.isEmpty){
            if currentElement  == "title" {
                postTitle += data
            }
            else if currentElement == "link" {
                webLink += data
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
        print("Bad XML File, Please validate")
    }

    func reloadFunc(_ sender: AnyObject){

        viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return feeds.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "webFeeds", for: indexPath)

        let feeds: Model = self.feeds[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = feeds.postTitle

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "webParse" {
            let feed: Model = feeds[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row]
            let pageView = segue.destination as! ViewController
            pageView.webLink = feed.webLink
        }
    }

    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser){

        self.tableView.reloadData();
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing();
    } 
}
```

Model.swift

```
//
//  Model.swift
//  WebView
//

import Foundation

class Model {
    var postTitle:String = ""
    var webLink:String = ""
    var currentElement:String = ""

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  WebView
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var showPage: UIWebView!
    var webLink: String = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let link : NSURL = NSURL(string: webLink)!
        let req : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: link as URL)
        showPage.loadRequest (req as URLRequest)
        showPage.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Screenshot upon reloading

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is adding object at last is because you need to empty your array before refreshing data. Also never call `viewDidLoad` explicitly what you need to do is make one method that make this API request and call that method from viewDidLoad and your refresh method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //call function to get xml data
    self.getData()

    //reload
    reload!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to reload the page")
    reload!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.reloadFunc), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(reload)
    reload.endRefreshing()
}

func getData() {
    //Make array empty first
    feeds = []

    let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://froshgeek.com/feed")!
    let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: urlToSend as URL)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}
```

Now call this `getData` function in your refresh action method `reloadFunc`

```
func reloadFunc(_ sender: AnyObject){

    self.getData()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, you're gold :)

Comment: Thanks bro, can you tell me why should we never call viewDidLoad in that manner like I was doing?